# Python: Insert space between every element in a list with one line description in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a simple Encrype and Decrype system. I have a syntax question like the topic above, please take a look.

```
def en_num(pw):
    en1 = [int(x) for x in pw]
    for i in en1:
        numstr = "".join(bin(int(i))[2:])
        numstr += " "
    return numstr
```

For example, input is "1 2", the output will be "1 10"
This can geve me the right output, however, I am trying to write this for loop in one line, like this

```
def en_num(pw):
    en1 = [int(x) for x in pw]
    numstr = "".join(bin(int(i))[2:] for i in en1)
    return numstr
```

I don't know how to add the space between in this syntax, the result is "110"
Please take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space between the quotes on your join statement:

`numstr = " ".join(bin(int(i))[2:] for i in en1)`

That will separate each number.

Comment: The output still remain 110 in this case

Comment: I got all numbers separated by a space when I ran this. What kind of value are you iterating over?